# How to run two maven surefire plugins with different configurations?

Tags: maven, parallel-processing, maven-surefire-plugin

I have 2 test suites. One can be run in parallel and the other must be run sequentially. See definition below.

What I see is that only the second one runs.

I tried to define 2 plugins. Didn't work.

I tried to give them differen execution ID. Didn't work.

I tried to put the configuration under the execution, but got an error that the elements under the configuration aren't allowed, like `failIfNoSpecifiedTests`.

**Any idea how I can run the suites with different configurations - one in parallel and the other sequentially?**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>SequentialTests</id>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/SequentialTests.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>ParallelTests</id>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/ParallelTests.java</include>
        </includes>
        <threadCount>10</threadCount>
        <parallel>classes</parallel>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Sequential sounds like integration tests where as ParallelTests sounds like unit tests?

Comment: Both are unit tests. The ones that aren't designed to run in parallel must be run sequentially.

Comment: Sorry if they can't run in parallel then they are no unit tests...

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure a single surefire plugin with multiple executions in the plugin management section of your build. So something like the following:

```
   <build>
     <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <! any common config-->
          </configuration>
          <!-- multiple executions-->
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>default-test</id>
              <configuration>
                <!-- skip default execution since we want to run tests in separate groups, remove this execution if not required for you -->
                <skip>true</skip>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>firstTestGroup</id>
              <configuration>
                <includes>
                  <include>**/*BlahTest</include>
                </includes>
              </configuration>
              <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>secondTestGroup</id>
              <configuration>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>**/*BlahTest</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </configuration>
              <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

Comment: How is this solution different than @roiros' suggestion?

Comment: It is more explicit and specifies where to put it - plugin management section - with a concrete working example that shows the default execution that needs to be skipped (or overridden if you want) etc.. this worked for me with failsafe-plugin (which extends surefire) as well as other plugins.. you have put in a comment mentioning that it is not working for the previous solution by @roiros, thought this might help.. is it still not working?

Answer (score 0):

Please put the different configurations under the 2 separate execution nodes - instead as a top level element, as a top level element they are overloading each other while under separate execution nodes they can live 'side by side'
e.g:

```
<execution> 
  <id>SequentialTests</id>
  <configuration>...<configuration>
</execution>

<execution>
  <id>ParallelTests</id>
  <configuration>...<configuration>
</execution>
```

Comment: Not working, All configuration sub-tags are being ignored, like `<includes>`, `<failIfNoSpecifiedTests>`, etc. Even IDEA highlights configuration sub-elements in red, to indicate they aren't accepted.